# Re enter Germany with a student Visa

Tags: germany, student-visas

Hi i am currently a student in Germany and my student Visa expires at 12-10-2023.
I want to travel to my home country and re enter Germany at 13-9-2023 is that possible?
(I want to re enter Germany before the visa expires by 1 month).

Comment: Of course. Why should it not be?

Comment: I am afraid , if they shouldn't let me enter with a one month only visa.

Comment: If a visa allows multiple entries, having one month validity left is not a problem. I was once issued a 11-day visa to Denmark (long before both Denmark and my country joined the Schengen Area). We presented our itinerary to the Danish embassy and they gave us visas for exactly 11 days. So one month left is perfectly fine. Just make sure not to overstay.